# JHipster - Using existing database in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, jhipster

My question is related to use `Hibernate` into `JHipster`.

I'd like to know if there exists a way to work with Hibernate by using an already existing database without generating manually all the entities.

I'd like to know if there exists this sort of reverse engineering way to proceed.

If not, I would like to know what is the best strategy to follow in order to work with an existing database (I'm working with MySQL).

Comment: Have you tried this jhipster module ? https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper